# How to sort by year and month in R (using as.yearmon from zoo package)

Tags: r, sorting, zoo

I'm trying to sort a vector with year and month information. I'm getting year and month from a Date type variable. Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
example <- as.Date(c("2010-04-22", "2010-04-26", "2010-04-26",
  "2010-06-04", "2010-06-07", "2010-06-18", "2010-06-21",
  "2010-07-14", "2010-07-16", "2010-07-30", "2010-08-20"))

mes_ano <- as.character(as.yearmon(as.Date(example)))

mes_ano <- factor(mes_ano, levels = c(unique(mes_ano),
 "mai 2010", "set 2010", "out 2010", "nov 2010"))
```

Now I would like to sort mes_ano by year and month, but I don't know how.

Actually, my real goal is to sort the levels, since I'll make a plot with ggplot2 and I need the levels to be sorted. But I thought that it would make our life easier if I just asked about sorting a vector. Then I can figure out how to sort levels.

Comment: Why not just sort `example` instead?

Comment: Because when I change mes_ano to factor, mes_ano isn't sorted in the right way. I could manually set the order of levels for each factor, but in my actual dataset the number of levels is too big, so it would be really burdensome.

Comment: How about just: `plot(as.yearmon(example), rnorm(11))`

Comment: I need my Dates to be on month-year format only, because I'll do some aggregation (using plyr package) by month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to use the Potuguese month names. Let's go:

Your data:

```
example <- as.Date(c("2010-04-22", "2010-04-26", "2010-04-26",
                     "2010-06-04", "2010-06-07", "2010-06-18", "2010-06-21",
                     "2010-07-14", "2010-07-16", "2010-07-30", "2010-08-20"))
```

We need a vector with these names:

```
port_mon <- c("jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun",
              "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez")
```

Now, sort the data:

```
ex_sorted <- sort(example)
```

Choose the correct month names in Portuguese:

```
month_names <- port_mon[as.numeric(format(ex_sorted, "%m"))]
```

Combine months and years:

```
mes_ano <- paste(month_names, format(ex_sorted, "%Y"))
```

Create factor:

```
mes_ano_fac <- factor(as.yearmon(ex_sorted), labels = unique(mes_ano))
```

Plot (with meaningless data on the y-axis for illustration purposes):

```
library(ggplot)

qplot(x = mes_ano_fac, y = seq(length(example)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it and if it works (as it seems to do), I'll chose it as my accepted answer. Thanks again.